# How can I count in my pandas dataframe how many times the data column has reached the threshold, with different threshold conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As described in the question, I want to count in a new column how often my threshold has been reached by each data. I have different conditions to meet the threhsold. There are exactly two conditions. Either greater than/equal to or less than/equal to the threshold.

My structure of the Panda Dataframe looks like this:

```
Number Metric  Threshold   Data1    Data2   Data3
  1     'M1'      10         12       8       11
  2     'M2'      20         20       14       1
  3     'M3'      30         50       22      44
  4     'M4'      40         39       28      41
```

In this case are the conditions for Metric 1 and Metric 2: Greater than/equal the threshold (Threshold <=) and for Metric 3 and Metric 4: Less than/equal the threshold (Threshold >=).
Below is an example of the result with the defined conditions shown.

The result with the different conditions should look like this:

```
Number Metric  Threshold   Data1    Data2   Data3  Threshold_Met_Count
  1     'M1'     10         12       8       11        2
  2     'M2'     20         20       14       1        1
  3     'M3'     30         50       22      44        1
  4     'M4'     40         39       28      41        2
```

I made my conditions into a dictionary. After that I tried to iterate over it and make a comparison with the respective column and the threshold column. But unfortunately I could not do it.

EDIT:

I used the solution from @mozway.
mozway solution:

```
    mask1 = df['Metric'].isin(['M1', 'M2'])
mask2 = df['Metric'].isin(['M3', 'M4'])

df2 = df.filter(like='Data')
df['Threshold_Met_Count'] =  (
   df2[mask1].ge(df['Threshold'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
  +df2[mask2].le(df['Threshold'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
 )
```

I get this error message:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

The problem was that my metric column has string data and my threshold data has float data. So I changed the code in this way and this fits with my use case:

```
    mask1 = df['Number'].isin([1, 2])
mask2 = df['Number'].isin([3, 4])

df2 = df.filter(like='Data').astype(float)
df['Threshold_Met_Count'] =  (
   df2[mask1].ge(df['Threshold'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
  +df2[mask2].le(df['Threshold'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
 )
```

Comment: You could use numpy and pandas for that

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` (`df` being your dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple conditions (with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)) and sum:

```
mask1 = df['Metric'].isin(['M1', 'M2'])
mask2 = df['Metric'].isin(['M3', 'M4'])

df2 = df.filter(like='Data')
df['Threshold_Met_Count'] =  (
   df2[mask1].ge(df['Threshold'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
  +df2[mask2].le(df['Threshold'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
 )
```

A more hacky approach but that requires a single comparison, would be to use a mapping dictionary and [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
# -1 = ≥ threshold, 1 = ≤ threshold
flag = {'M1': -1, 'M2': -1, 'M3': 1, 'M4': 1}

df['Threshold_Met_Count'] = (
   np.sign(df.filter(like='Data').sub(df['Threshold'], axis=0))
     .ne(df['Metric'].map(flag), axis=0).sum(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   Number Metric  Threshold  Data1  Data2  Data3  Threshold_Met_Count
0       1     M1         10     12      8     11                    2
1       2     M2         20     20     14      1                    1
2       3     M3         30     50     22     44                    1
3       4     M4         40     39     28     41                    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. When I try to run the first code, I get this Error message: "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'".
I can't figure out where to change/cast the columns right, to solve this error.

The second code is also giving a error message. Error Message: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'"

Comment: @newbie yes, you have likely strings. Can you try `df2 = df.filter(like='Data').astype(float)`? (or `df.filter(like='Data').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`) If you have an error, this means you also have non-numeric data, can you then provide a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: I tried. Still the same error message. But I tried to set the Number column as filter. Now it works and counts. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @newbie glad it worked. You might want to provide a reproducible example if you need us to do further debugging.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add the code with the error message in my question and / or that what works? I update my question right away

Comment: Rather a reproducible sample of the data that causes an error. I gave you a command as comment to the question (`df.to_dict('list')`), or if you have too many rows: `df.head(n).to_dict('list')` where `n` is a reasonable number of rows

Comment: Okay, I will edit my question with the datatypes which are in my dataframe. The problem was that the metric columns has strings in it like "M1", "M2", ..., etc. while the threshold and data column are filled with float data.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define the conditions as a dictionary
conditions = {'M1': '>=', 'M2': '>=', 'M3': '<=', 'M4': '<='}

# Define a function to count the number of metrics that meet the condition
def count_threshold_met(row):
    count = 0
    for metric, condition in conditions.items():
        if condition == '>=':
            if row[metric] >= row['Threshold']:
                count += 1
        elif condition == '<=':
            if row[metric] <= row['Threshold']:
                count += 1
    return count

# Apply the function to each row of the DataFrame to create a new column
df['Threshold_Met_Count'] = df.apply(count_threshold_met, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. When I try to run the code, I get this Error message: "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'".
I can't figure out where to change/cast the columns right, to solve this error.